# Listing all records with realm causes crash

Tags: swift, realm

I am running this code for list all users in realm:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   var allShuffle=ShufflePerson.allObjects()
   for var i = 1; i <= Int(allShuffle.count); ++i {
       var someIntToUInt : UInt = UInt(i);
       println("someun \(someIntToUInt)")
       let shufflePerson = allShuffle.objectAtIndex(someIntToUInt) as! ShufflePerson  //If I remove this line my code is not crashing
   }
}
```

My code is crashing with following error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: This website works on the questions and answers principle. But you don't ask anything, just list your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` should start at 0 and end at array.count - 1. In your case you can just use "<" instead of "<="  `i < Int(allShuffle.count)`.

You could also use the fast enumeration and not have any pb with objects count and index:

```
for object in ShufflePerson.allObjects() {
    let shufflePerson = object as! ShufflePerson
    println("someun \(shufflePerson)")
}
```